# Refresh Index, Serialize and Stats are throwing errors after upgrading Nest to 1.7.1

Tags: c#, nest

I have existing code that refreshes particular index like below:

```
_elasticClient.Refresh(_testIndexName);
```

Serialize a query like below :

```
_elasticClient.Serialize(query);
```

And check index status like below:

```
elasticClient.Stats(_testIndexName);
```

Below are the errors:

'Nest.ElasticClient' does not contain a definition for 'Serialize' and no extension method 'Serialize' accepting a first argument of type 'Nest.ElasticClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The best overloaded method match for 'Nest.ElasticClient.Refresh(System.Func)' has some invalid arguments

'Nest.ElasticClient' does not contain a definition for 'Stats' and no extension method 'Stats' accepting a first argument of type 'Nest.ElasticClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

All the above things are not working after upgrading.Do i have any other alternative option other than downgrading my version?

Comment: What version of elasticsearch do you use?

Comment: i have upgraded recently to 1.7.5

Comment: May you post more details about the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Propably you are upgreading NEST from 0.x. This is how you can handle your calls in NEST 1.x.

1. Change `_elasticClient.Refresh(_testIndexName)` to `_elasticClient.Refresh(f => f.Indices(_testIndexName))`
2. Change `_elasticClient.Serialize(query)` to  `_elasticClient.Serializer.Serialize(query)` or `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_elasticClient.Serializer.Serialize(query))` if you want to get string
3. Change `elasticClient.Stats(_testIndexName)` to `elasticClient.IndicesStats(i => i.Index(_testIndexName))`

Hope it will make your migration easier.

Comment: Thank you @rob , '_elasticClient.Serializer.Serialize(query)' is returning byte.so ,each time i am converting it to json.

Comment: Ohh yes, I forgot about this. I'll update my answer.